# Pattern to do infinite animation in javascript without stack overflow

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, infinite

I have the following pattern to repeat an animation (itself consisting of x frames), t times:

```
sprite.prototype.loop = function(t,animation_name,frame_delay) {
    if(t > 0) {
        function next_run() {
            this.loop(t-1,animation_name,frame_delay);
        } 
        this.run(animation_name,frame_delay,next_run);
      }
    };

sprite.prototype.run = function(animation_name,frame_delay,frame_count,callback) {
    frame_count ||= 0;
    var s = this;
    if(frame_count < this.paths[animation_name].length) { // x frames
        setTimeout( function () {
            s.blit(s.paths[animation_name][frame_count]);
            s.run(animation_name,frame_delay,frame_count+1);
            }, frame_delay );
        }
    } else {
        if(!!callback) callback();
    }

super_mario.loop(10000,'mushroom_death',40);
```

Clearly if x*t is larger than the maximum stack depth, a stack overflow will occur.

**Question**: Can this pattern be extended to the case of running an animation an infinite number of times, or is there a more correct way to do the infinite loop case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rewrite your `loop` function as follows:

```
sprite.prototype.loop = function (t, animation_name, frame_delay) {
    var s = this;
    var frames = s.paths[animation_name];
    var x = frames.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        for (var frame_count = 0; frame_count < x; frame_count++) {
            setTimeout(function (frame_count) {
                s.blit(frames[frame_count]);
            }, (i * x + frame_count) * frame_delay, frame_count);
        }
    }
};
```

That's it. There won't be any stack overflow because there's no recursion.

**Edit:** As just2n mentioned there's another problem with your code. There won't be any delay between two same frames as you're *in effect* calling `setTimeout` for all the same frames at the same time. Hence the animation will only occur once no matter what the value of `t`.

Comment: Is there any (memory/execution) problem with setting up this many `setTimeout`s in a row?

Comment: There is the issue that `setTimeout` has no guarantee that actions will occur at the given delay. Instead, the renderer should look at the time and decide what frame it should be on in something like a `requestAnimationFrame` loop. This way if someone were to minimize the window or switch tabs and then come back, rendering would continue at the correct place.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` doesn't inherit the caller's stack frame, so you'd only have to worry about `t` here, though there's really no reason this can't be trivially written iteratively so that stack size isn't a concern:

```
sprite.prototype.loop = function(t, animation_name, frame_delay){
    while (t--){
        this.run(animation_name, frame_delay);
    }
};
```

However, it feels like this code isn't doing what you expect it to do. This is literally running the animation `t` times in parallel, since the `setTimeout` calls in `run` will interleave one another. I'm not sure I can understand how that would be an intended effect, since each one of the `t` deferred callbacks would each perform the exact same `blit` operation here, so there would be no discernible difference.

Comment: It's not that a call to `setTimeout` isn't pushed onto the call stack. Every function is. What happens when you call `setTimeout` is that it defers the execution of the specified function. Hence both `setTimeout` and the calling function return before the specified function is executed. Thus the call stack is cleared before the specified function executes.

Comment: This was the right answer until I updated my code to include the callback for the next run. The callback is recursing the loop function, so it can't be unrolled like that anymore.